# Firebase - google Auth LocalHost

Tags: angular, firebase, google-oauth

I am developing a website with Angular/Firebase which is already online, to test the modifications I launch ng serve, before I could identify myself on the localhost without problem, for a week and without having to modify anything that is no longer possible. The localhost is referenced in allowed domains.

I don't know what to do, do you have any suggestions?

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {firebase, firebaseui} from "firebaseui-angular";
import Config = firebaseui.auth.Config;
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {AngularFireAuth} from "@angular/fire/compat/auth";
import {User} from "@model/user";
import {UserService} from "@services/user.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

  ui!: firebaseui.auth.AuthUI;
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private router: Router,
              public user: UserService) {
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.ui.delete();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.afAuth.app.then(app => {
      const uiConfig: Config  = {
        signInOptions: [
          firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
        ],
        callbacks: {
          signInSuccessWithAuthResult: this.onLoginSuccessful.bind(this)
        }
      };
      this.ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(app.auth());
      this.ui.start("#firebaseUi-auth-container",uiConfig);
      this.ui.disableAutoSignIn();
      this.router.navigateByUrl("workShopList");
    });
  }

  onLoginSuccessful(result:any):boolean{
    console.log("la");
    if(result){
      const newUser: User = {
        email: result.user.email,
        firstname: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.given_name,
        image: result.user.photoURL,
        lastname: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.family_name,
        uuid: firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid ? <string>firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid : "",
        key: ""
      }

      if(firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid){
        this.user.createUser(newUser).subscribe();
      }else {
        console.log("Erreur creation de l'utilisateur");
        this.router.navigateByUrl("");
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i i understand you correctely you are not able to access the locakhost on you system that is supposed to serve your project .meanwhile i would suggest you the following check.

1. Check Port Configuration: Verify that the port you are using for the localhost is not being used by another app. because as you know By default, angular uses port 4200 when we command-  ng serve and if another application is already using this port, you can specify a different port by running ng serve --port <port_number>.
2. Clear Browser Cache: Clear your browser cache because sometime cached data can interfere with the functioning of the website then try accessing the localhost again.
3. Check Firebase Hosting Configuration: check that the localhost is still listed as an allowed domain in your Firebase Hosting. You can check it by checking the firebase.json file in your project's root directory. Look for the hosting section and verify that the allowedDomains property includes localhost.

you might want to go trough this [Test your web app locally, share changes with others, then deploy live](https://%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/test-preview-deploy)

4. Restart Development Server: Restart the development server by stopping ng serve and running it again. This can help resolve any temporary issues or conflicts.

if all of above did not resolve your issue then we need more info from your project inside

Comment: Hi,
I checked the different steps, but it still doesn't work.

Using ng serve, I reach my application but I cannot authenticate with google, but online with the same version of the application, no problem.
thank you for your help